# Swift Parse.com data query to dictionary

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get data from parse.com and add the data into an array or dictionary. I keep getting errors does anyone know the best solution to get data from parse. Is it possible to return the dictionary and use it in another function?

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func getQuote() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Quote")
    var quote = PFObject(className:"Quote")
    var quoteDictionary: [String:String]!

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {

                    var quoteText = object["quoteText"] as String
                    var quoteAuthor = object["quoteAuthor"] as String

                    quoteDictionary[quoteAuthor] = quoteText

                    println(quoteDictionary)
                    println(quoteAuthor)
                    println(quoteText)

                }


            }

        } else {
            println("Error")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are quoteText and quoteAuthor both string columns, and do both columns contain non-nil values in every row?  If not, you'll be inserting a nil into a dictionary that is declared as taking string values.  As an aside, what's wrong with just using the PFObjects, why reduce them to dictionaries?

Comment: Yes, quoteText and quoteAuthor are both string columns and they both contain values.  With PFObject can you give me an example. I have seen and attempted to use many ways described in the documentation but I have got non to work. You do not have to help me but if you can give me a few pointers it would be great.

Comment: I'd love to be more helpful, but I'm not very articulate in swift.  In objective-c apps, however, I regularly use PFObjects as they are, as returned from parse, treating them as if they were dictionaries.  They respond to allKeys and objectForKey: and setObject:forKey:.  That's usually 99% of what I need.

Comment: Is it possible to return the values in the for loop?

Comment: Your function could declare a completion block in the same way the parse functions do, or you could assign the results to some instance property of the object calling parse.  i.e., the normal pattern if the class were a table view controller, would be to (in the find completion block) assign the results to a datasource array and have the table view reload.

Answer (score 0):

Play it safe and use defaults:

```
let quoteText = object["quoteText"] as? String ?? ""
let quoteAuthor = object["quoteAuthor"] as? String ?? ""
```

This safely handles empty values.